# modify a variable out of a

Tags: python, function

I defined distGPX function in a saperated file and I imported it into my main file.

```
def distGPX(Date, Distance):

    Date1, Distance1 = Date, Distance

    size = len(GPX1)

    for n in range(0, size):
        if '.gpx' not in GPX1[size - n - 1]:

            Date1.pop(size - n - 1)
            Distance1.pop(size - n - 1)


    return Date1, Distance1
```

In the main file I call function this way

```
newDate, newDistance = distGPX(Date, Distance)
```

where Date and Distance were not changed. The problem is that at main program variables Date and Distance are change the same way as Date1 and Distance1.

Anyone can explain me the problem?

Comment: Lists are passed by reference. You have to clone them to use in that way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python.